# bug in geom_map when combined with coord_map?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following is based on an example from the help page for geom_map:

```
crimes <- data.frame(state = tolower(rownames(USArrests)), USArrests) 
library(reshape2) # for melt 
crimesm <- melt(crimes, id = 1) 
if (require(maps)) { 
  states_map <- map_data("state") 
  ggplot(crimes, aes(map_id = state)) + 
        geom_map(aes(fill = Murder), map = states_map) + 
        expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat) + 
        coord_map(project = "polyconic") 
}
```

It gives this error:

> Error in validDetails.polygon(x) : 
>     'x' and 'y' and 'id' must all be same length

The only change from the example is the addition of coord_map.

I think this may be a bug in geom_map, similar to what existed previously in geom_ribbon before it was fixed by Hadley: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/112

Can anyone confirm this? If it's a bug, how do I report it?

David

Comment: Well, it seems that `?coord_map` has the disclaimer that it is still experimental, so perhaps we shouldn't be too surprised. I see your post on the mailing list didn't get much attention. You might try posting on the ggplot2-dev mailing list, or perhaps filing a bug report on github.

Comment: You can report it a the exact link you provided. https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2  Click on Issues and then click on new issue.